# Connecting a horizontally angled sink drain connection

Tags: plumbing

We recently acquired a second hand kitchen, and we're trying to do the plumbing for the first time all by ourselves.

For regular cases, I can buy kits that would pretty much have all the PVC piping and connections I would need. However in my case, the sinks drain is horizontally angled and I am not sure what kind of connections to get in this case. Plus I need to connect the dishwasher here too!

Some measurement's:

- Sink's pipe inner width is 40mm.
- Pipe connection poking through the hole is also 40mm.

[image: current situation]

P.S. I live in Germany currently, and all the stuff I can find online is mostly for industrial use (as far as I can tell). So if anyone could give some pointers what's the best place to pick up (slightly) custom piping, that would be awesome.